# ParserError: Function, variable, struct or modifier declaration expected. contract MyContract { ^------^

Tags: solidity

I'm trying to interact with kyberswap protocol via solidity, when attempting to compile my code(this is from kybers github) I receive the following parser error

> " ParserError: Function, variable, struct or modifier declaration expected. contract MyContract { ^------^"

```
contract MyContract {
    IERC20 internal constant ETH_TOKEN_ADDRESS = IERC20(0xEeeeeEeeeEeEeeEeEeEeeEEEeeeeEeeeeeeeEEeE);
    IKyberNetworkProxy kyberProxy;
    address payable public platformWallet;
    uint256 public platformFeeBps;

    // constructor
    // _platformWallet: To receive platform fees
    // _platformFeeBps: Platform fee amount in basis points
    constructor(
        IKyberNetworkProxy _kyberProxy,
        address payable _platformWallet,
        uint256 _platformFeeBps
        ) public
    {
        kyberProxy = _kyberProxy;
        platformWallet = _platformWallet;
        platformFeeBps = _platformFeeBps;
    }

    /// @dev Get the conversion rate for exchanging srcQty of srcToken to destToken
    function getConversionRates(
        IERC20 srcToken,
        IERC20 destToken,
        uint256 srcQty
    ) public
      view
      returns (uint256)
    {
      return kyberProxy.getExpectedRateAfterFee(srcToken, destToken, srcQty, platformFeeBps, '');
    }

    /// @dev Swap from srcToken to destToken (including ether)
    function executeSwap(
        IERC20 srcToken,
        uint256 srcQty,
        IERC20 destToken,
        address payable destAddress,
        uint256 maxDestAmount
    ) external payable {
        if (srcToken != ETH_TOKEN_ADDRESS) {
            // check that the token transferFrom has succeeded
            // we recommend using OpenZeppelin's SafeERC20 contract instead
            // NOTE: msg.sender must have called srcToken.approve(thisContractAddress, srcQty)
            require(srcToken.transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), srcQty), "transferFrom failed");

            // mitigate ERC20 Approve front-running attack, by initially setting
            // allowance to 0
            require(srcToken.approve(address(kyberProxy), 0), "approval to 0 failed");

            // set the spender's token allowance to tokenQty
            require(srcToken.approve(address(kyberProxy), srcQty), "approval to srcQty failed");
        }

        // Get the minimum conversion rate
        uint256 minConversionRate = kyberProxy.getExpectedRateAfterFee(
            srcToken,
            destToken,
            srcQty,
            platformFeeBps,
            '' // empty hint
        );

        // Execute the trade and send to destAddress
        kyberProxy.tradeWithHintAndFee{value: msg.value}(
            srcToken,
            srcQty,
            destToken,
            destAddress,
            maxDestAmount,
            minConversionRate,
            platformWallet,
            platformFeeBps,
            '' // empty hint
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi there. Can you include the rest of the code as well?

Comment: From the error message it appears something is wrong before the contract. Perhaps a `;` is missing in a previous line?